# Solving the inequality $|-9v| \le 54$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

If I have a Problem like $|-9v| \leq 54$, is it okay to break it up like $(-9v) \leq54$ and $-(-9v) \leq54$ and solve? Also, you can just make it positive so that $(9v) \leq54$ and $-(9v)\leq54$ and solve? I just want to know if both ways of thinking are correct.

Thanks

Comment: If $v$ is real,it will be $-54\le -9v<54, 6\ge v\ge -6$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yeah I know how to solve, I just want to know if both ways of thinking are correct.

Comment: ya, we can take in either way as corroborated  by my answer

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Oh okay got it, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$|x|\le a\iff -a\le x< a$ if real $a\ge0$

$|-x|\le a\iff -a\le -x\le a\iff -a\le x\le a$